# Show an icon on hover with css

Tags: html, css

I just want to show an icon on hover with css. I tried it like this but its not working. :(

HTML:

```
<button class="casino-btn">BONUS<font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'gift']" class="bonus-icon"/></button>
```

CSS:

```
.bonus-icon {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .casino-btn:hover + .bonus-icon {
        visibility: visible;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 reason this isn't working for you:

1. To include a Font Awesome icon in HTML, you use it like this (see "How to use" for this [Font Awesome icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/gift?style=solid)):

```
<i class="fa fa-gift bonus-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

2. When you use the `+` in a CSS selector like this `.casino-btn:hover + .bonus-icon`, it means the *next* element, but `bonus-icon` is a *child* of the button. You just use a space to target a child, e.g.

```
.casino-btn:hover .bonus-icon
```

**Working Example:**

```css
.bonus-icon {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.casino-btn:hover .bonus-icon {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
<button class="casino-btn">BONUS
    <i class="fa fa-gift bonus-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, it works now! I am currently working with Nuxt and the sad part is that I have to add Icons like this... Or is there an alternative?

Comment: @foka135 I'm not familiar with Nuxt so I'm afraid I don't know if there is an alternative :)